# Best organization of a Sage Project / Module

Tags: sage, project-organization

I would like to organize my Sage project in a way that reflects best practices. For example, for Python projects https://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/structure-of-a-python-project/ recommends

```
project_name/  
    project_name/  
        __init__.py  
        ...source code files...  
    test/  
        __init__.py  
        ...unit test files...  
    docs/  
        ...documentation files...  
    project_name.py  
    README.md  
    LICENSE.md  
    requirements.txt  
    .gitignore
```

How should this model be modified if I would like a package that can be imported to Sage and a sample jupyter notebook showcasing functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general rules for Python packages apply.

If deposited on PyPI, the package will be installable via pip with

```
$ pip install PACKAGE_NAME
```

There is a template for a Sage package at

- https://github.com/sagemath/sage_sample

with a lot of tips in its README.

See also some utilities at

- https://github.com/sagemath/sage-package